# Oracle SQL xml pivot with additional (non-aggregate) columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am looking for a way to include non-aggregate values in an xml pivot query. my code looks like the following:

```
select * from (
select country, month from travel
where <parameters, as far as i know irrelevant to the discussion>
pivot xml (
count(month) travellers,
for country in (select country from table_a where <parameters>)
)
```

Querying a table where every row represents a person travelling, so that the count of month will return the number of people travelling in that month.

This query returns the following xml:

```
<PivotSet>
    <item>
        <column name = "COUNTRY">AE</column>
        <column name = "TRAVELLERS">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name = "COUNTRY">AL</column>
        <column name = "TRAVELLERS">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name = "COUNTRY">BE</column>
        <column name = "TRAVELLERS">2</column>
    </item>
    <item>
    ...
    </item>
</PivotSet>
```

What i'd like is to get non-aggregate values for b and c, which i would expect would look like :

```
select * from (
select country, month from travel
where <parameters, irrelevant to the discussion>
pivot xml (
count(month) travellers,
for country, month in (select country, month from table_a where <parameters>)
)
```

but this does not work, as pivot seems to only allow non-aggregate values for one column.

I'd like to see the following xml returned:

```
<PivotSet>
    <item>
        <column name="MONTH">JANUARY</column>
        <column name = "COUNTRY">AE</column>
        <column name = "TRAVELLERS">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="MONTH">FEBRUARY</column>
        <column name = "COUNTRY">AL</column>
        <column name = "TRAVELLERS">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="MONTH">MARCH</column>
        <column name = "COUNTRY">BE</column>
        <column name = "TRAVELLERS">2</column>
    </item>
    <item>
    ...
    </item>
</PivotSet>
```

What are my options to make this work? Am I misunderstanding how the pivot function works?

Comment: It would be helpful to add some sample data, what your current query gets, and what your desired result would be - for that data. You're using an XML pivot but showing a relational result - are you currently converting that somehow? Or are you trying to get a dynamic set of columns - are the months supposed to be Jan-Dec (from any year), or year specific, or up to current date, or something else?

Comment: I'll update with the current xml result returned from this query; i included the relational  result more for illustrative purposes -- i can convert the xml to something more appropriate later on but for right now i just need to get a result that  represents the relational result example I included.

Comment: Just updated to include the requested information

Comment: The first query works, but it doesn't deliver the expected results. query 2 returns the error : "ORA-01738: missing IN keyword".

Comment: Your first query has an extra comma and is missing a closing parenthesis.... Aside from those, the second one is missing parentheses around the pivot expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see from the code snippets in the question, and ignore what I think are errors you've introduced creating the question; you just need to add parentheses around the two columns you're pivoting on:

```
select *
from (
  select country, month from travel
  where <parameters, as far as i know irrelevant to the discussion>
)
pivot xml (
  count(*) travellers
  for (country, month) in (select country from table_a where <parameters>)
)
```

[The pivot clause syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) shows you can either have a single expression, or a comma-separated list of expressions *in parentheses*. Without the parentheses, it isn't expecting the second expression (`, month`) and throws the "ORA-01738: missing IN keyword" because that *is* what it's expecting to see next.

Demo with a CTE, and assuming you're getting the distinct months/countries from the same table for simplicity:

```
-- CTE for dummy data
with travel (country, month) as (
  select 'US', date '2017-01-01' from dual connect by level <= 3
  union all select 'US', date '2017-02-01' from dual connect by level <= 1
  union all select 'France', date '2017-01-01' from dual connect by level <= 1
  union all select 'France', date '2017-02-01' from dual connect by level <= 5
  union all select 'Spain', date '2017-01-01' from dual connect by level <= 5
  union all select 'Spain', date '2017-02-01' from dual connect by level <= 2
)
-- actual query
select xmlserialize(document country_month_xml indent size=2)
from (
  select country, month from travel
)
pivot xml (
  count(*) travellers
  for (country, month) in (select distinct country, month from travel)
);
```

which gets:

```
<PivotSet>
  <item>
    <column name="COUNTRY">France</column>
    <column name="MONTH">2017-01-01</column>
    <column name="TRAVELLERS">1</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name="COUNTRY">France</column>
    <column name="MONTH">2017-02-01</column>
    <column name="TRAVELLERS">5</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name="COUNTRY">Spain</column>
    <column name="MONTH">2017-01-01</column>
    <column name="TRAVELLERS">5</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name="COUNTRY">Spain</column>
    <column name="MONTH">2017-02-01</column>
    <column name="TRAVELLERS">2</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name="COUNTRY">US</column>
    <column name="MONTH">2017-01-01</column>
    <column name="TRAVELLERS">3</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name="COUNTRY">US</column>
    <column name="MONTH">2017-02-01</column>
    <column name="TRAVELLERS">1</column>
  </item>
</PivotSet>
```

I've added an XMLSerialize call just to make it more more readable...